# Different formats in one cell - Excel Web

Tags: excel, formatting, office365

In Microsoft Excel, desktop version, you can have different format styles within one cell.

Is it possible also in the web wersion of Office 365 Excel?

If it is, how can bw do it?

In example: how to have a green word and a red word in the same cell.

Comment: So create an example in a workbook then open that in the web version - you will soon see...

Comment: Yes, I have this already done but when we edit in the web version, necessary for editing the same sheet concurrently by N users, I can't find how to do the same. Thanks!